# find the stochastic differential eqution with ito

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, stochastic-processes

I was trying to do some ito problems but I don't grasp how to apply the formula (which is the process). If somebody could give me a hand it would be great! Thanks so much in advance.

I have the process $X_t$: $X_t=2+t+e^{B_t}$

with $B_t$ a Brownian motion.

I am supposed to find the EDS through Ito...

Comment: Please use dollar signs to bracket equations and underscores for lower indices.

Answer (score 1):

The intuitivistic approach is to compute $X_{t+dt}=X_t+dX_t$ from $B_{t+dt}=B_t+dB_t$ using $(dB_t)^2=dt$ and all higher powers and products with $dt$ set to zero.

\begin{align}
X_t+dX_t&=X_{t+dt}=2+(t+dt)+e^{B_t+dB_t} = X_t+dt+e^{B_t}(e^{dB_t}-1)\\
&=X_t+dt+e^{B_t}(dB_t+\tfrac12 dt)
\end{align}

where the exponential series

$$e^x-1=x+\tfrac12x^2+\tfrac16x^3+\dots+\tfrac1{n!}x^n+\dots$$

was used, with the indicated truncation.

---

And by the book, with $X=f(t,B)$ where $f(t,z)=2+t+\exp(z)$, one gets

\begin{align}
dX&=f_t\,dt+f_z\,dB+\tfrac12 f_{zz}d\langle B\rangle
=(f_t+\tfrac12f_{zz})dt+f_z\,dB\\
&= (1+\tfrac12\exp(B))dt+\exp(B)dB
\end{align}

Comment: +1. You might want to add the rigorous approach, which is rather simple in this setting.